# Elastic (animated) edges in graph with nodes exerting gravitational pull on neighbours?

Tags: cytoscape.js

Is there a layout extension for Cytoscape that enables a dynamic behavior similar to that of the Neo4j Browser, i.e. **when you drag a node**, its edges are elastic to some extend, but that **also drag connected nodes along part of the way** (I'd call it localized gravity)?

Update:
The example I'm working on uses the [CoSE Bilkent (compound) layout extension](https://github.com/cytoscape/cytoscape.js-cose-bilkent), but it doesn't seem to support the effect/animation I'm after out of the box. I had hoped the [scarcely documented](http://js.cytoscape.org/#layouts/cose) `{ gravity: 1 }` option might be related - after all, when a node pulls other nodes along, that could well be described as gravity - but changing the setting on a small sample graph had no such effect; some digging ensued and I now think that setting has to do with how close to the graph's center nodes are displayed. I then looked at all [layout demos](http://js.cytoscape.org/#demos), none seem to display the effect I'm after out of the box. AllegroViva appears to implement similar behavior ([video](https://youtu.be/HQBMfozLa4Y?t=77)), but from my understanding, it's rendering a time series in that video (so might just be manually redrawing the graph). Their website seems to be disfunct, too.

What I'm looking for is something easy, ideally out of the box, or something that can be implemented quickly. Unfortunately, **I'm not quite sure what the right search term would be** for what I want (especially in Cytoscape's domain). Hence me asking what is admittedly a very high-level question. Today, I found out **Visjs calls it [physics events](http://visjs.org/examples/network/events/physicsEvents.html)** (or at least uses the effect I'm after as part of that demo) - but as I mentioned, `gravity` in Cytoscape is apparently not what I'm looking for. At this point, however, I'm **merely trying to establish if Cytoscape is the right library**, or whether I need to look at others, like [Alchemy (cf. its Philosophers' Relatedness example](http://graphalchemist.github.io/Alchemy/#/examples)).

Comment: This question does not show any research effort or code. It is unclear and not useful because of that. Please add code and context, so that we can see which specific roadblock you ran into. Judging by your karma, you don't really need a [Tour in the Help Center](https://stackoverflow.com/tour), but please consider editing the question. Thanks

Comment: Although there may be some valid usecases for using an infinite layout, they are very rare.  In most cases, using an infinite layout makes interacting with the graph slower and more difficult for your users.  It certainly looks flashy, but it's not without cost to UX.  That being said, you can use an infinite force-directed layout in Cytoscape if you want.  Stephan T. has a good answer for that.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

### **Answer:**

Thank you for editing the question, I think i can help you with this one. Cytoscape.js has this feature buried deep in the [extension layouts](http://js.cytoscape.org/#extensions/layout-extensions), specifically in [cytoscape.js-cola](https://github.com/cytoscape/cytoscape.js-cola). The layout is a physics layout with "springy" like nodes, so that the distance between them stays the same. The catch here is, that in the paragraph [Notes](https://github.com/cytoscape/cytoscape.js-cola#notes), the author describes this:

> - If you want to maintain interactivity, you probably should not mix infinite: true with fit: true. Fitting naturally changes the zoom level, making dragging misaligned and feel weird to users --- though it still works technically. Better to just fit: false when infinite: true, and cy.center() or cy.fit() on layoutready.
> - The alignment option isn't as flexible as the raw Cola option. Here, only integers can be used to specify relative positioning, so it's a bit limited. If you'd like to see a more sophisticated implementation, please send a pull request.

### **Code:**

So this example should work (note that the nodes can be moved, but they tend to stay in formation because of their already optimal position):

```js
document.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", function() {
  var cy = (window.cy = cytoscape({
    container: document.getElementById("cy"),
    autounselectify: true,

    boxSelectionEnabled: false,
    layout: {
      name: "cola",
      infinite: true,
      fit: false
    },
    style: [{
        selector: "node",
        css: {
          "background-color": "#f92411"
        }
      },
      {
        selector: "edge",
        css: {
          "line-color": "#f92411"
        }
      }
    ],
    elements: {
      nodes: [{
          data: {
            id: "1",
            label: "P"
          }
        },
        {
          data: {
            id: "2",
            label: "sucrose phosphate phosphatase"
          }
        },
        {
          data: {
            id: "4",
            label: "sucrose 6-phosphate"
          }
        },
        {
          data: {
            id: "6",
            label: "sucrose"
          }
        },
        {
          data: {
            id: "8",
            label: "invertase"
          }
        },
        {
          data: {
            id: "10",
            label: "fructose"
          }
        },
        {
          data: {
            id: "12",
            label: "fructokinase"
          }
        },
        {
          data: {
            id: "14",
            label: "fructose 6-phosphate"
          }
        },
        {
          data: {
            id: "20",
            label: "phosphoglucose isomerase"
          }
        },
        {
          data: {
            id: "22",
            label: "glucose 6-phosphate"
          }
        },
        {
          data: {
            id: "28",
            label: "glucose"
          }
        },
        {
          data: {
            id: "30",
            label: "hexokinase"
          }
        },
        {
          data: {
            id: "33",
            label: "sucrose synthase"
          }
        },
        {
          data: {
            id: "36",
            label: "UDP - glucose"
          }
        },
        {
          data: {
            id: "38",
            label: "sucrose phosphate synthase"
          }
        },
        {
          data: {
            id: "41",
            label: "UDP"
          }
        },
        {
          data: {
            id: "44",
            label: "fructose 6-phosphate"
          }
        },
        {
          data: {
            id: "46",
            label: "ATP"
          }
        },
        {
          data: {
            id: "47",
            label: "ATP"
          }
        },
        {
          data: {
            id: "52",
            label: "ATP"
          }
        },
        {
          data: {
            id: "57",
            label: "ADP"
          }
        },
        {
          data: {
            id: "66",
            label: "PP"
          }
        },
        {
          data: {
            id: "71",
            label: "UTP"
          }
        },
        {
          data: {
            id: "76",
            label: "UDP glucose pyrophosphorylase"
          }
        },
        {
          data: {
            id: "80",
            label: "glucose 1-phosphate"
          }
        },
        {
          data: {
            id: "86",
            label: "phospho- glucomutase (cPGM)"
          }
        },
        {
          data: {
            id: "89",
            label: "G1P transporter"
          }
        },
        {
          data: {
            id: "90",
            label: "P"
          }
        },
        {
          data: {
            id: "95",
            label: "P"
          }
        },
        {
          data: {
            id: "102",
            label: "P"
          }
        },
        {
          data: {
            id: "103",
            label: "P"
          }
        },
        {
          data: {
            id: "104",
            label: "G6P transporter"
          }
        },
        {
          data: {
            id: "109",
            label: "glucose 6-phosphate"
          }
        },
        {
          data: {
            id: "115",
            label: "phospho- glucomutase (cPGM)"
          }
        },
        {
          data: {
            id: "121",
            label: "glucose 1-phosphate"
          }
        },
        {
          data: {
            id: "128",
            label: "ADPglucose pyrophosphorylase (pAGPase)"
          }
        },
        {
          data: {
            id: "130",
            label: "ADP - glucose"
          }
        },
        {
          data: {
            id: "136",
            label: "PP"
          }
        },
        {
          data: {
            id: "141",
            label: "ATP"
          }
        },
        {
          data: {
            id: "148",
            label: "inorganic diphosphatase"
          }
        },
        {
          data: {
            id: "149",
            label: "P"
          }
        },
        {
          data: {
            id: "156",
            label: "phosphate transporter"
          }
        },
        {
          data: {
            id: "158",
            label: "P"
          }
        },
        {
          data: {
            id: "164",
            label: "starch synthase (simpl.)"
          }
        },
        {
          data: {
            id: "166",
            label: "ADP"
          }
        },
        {
          data: {
            id: "172",
            label: "starch"
          }
        },
        {
          data: {
            id: "178",
            label: "ATP/ADP transporter"
          }
        },
        {
          data: {
            id: "179",
            label: "ADP"
          }
        },
        {
          data: {
            id: "184",
            label: "ADP"
          }
        },
        {
          data: {
            id: "189",
            label: "ATP"
          }
        }
      ],
      edges: [{
          data: {
            source: "2",
            target: "1"
          }
        },
        {
          data: {
            source: "4",
            target: "2"
          }
        },
        {
          data: {
            source: "2",
            target: "6"
          }
        },
        {
          data: {
            source: "6",
            target: "8"
          }
        },
        {
          data: {
            source: "8",
            target: "10"
          }
        },
        {
          data: {
            source: "12",
            target: "14"
          }
        },
        {
          data: {
            source: "14",
            target: "20"
          }
        },
        {
          data: {
            source: "20",
            target: "22"
          }
        },
        {
          data: {
            source: "8",
            target: "28"
          }
        },
        {
          data: {
            source: "28",
            target: "30"
          }
        },
        {
          data: {
            source: "30",
            target: "22"
          }
        },
        {
          data: {
            source: "6",
            target: "33"
          }
        },
        {
          data: {
            source: "33",
            target: "10"
          }
        },
        {
          data: {
            source: "33",
            target: "36"
          }
        },
        {
          data: {
            source: "36",
            target: "38"
          }
        },
        {
          data: {
            source: "38",
            target: "4"
          }
        },
        {
          data: {
            source: "38",
            target: "41"
          }
        },
        {
          data: {
            source: "41",
            target: "33"
          }
        },
        {
          data: {
            source: "44",
            target: "38"
          }
        },
        {
          data: {
            source: "52",
            target: "12"
          }
        },
        {
          data: {
            source: "12",
            target: "57"
          }
        },
        {
          data: {
            source: "46",
            target: "30"
          }
        },
        {
          data: {
            source: "30",
            target: "47"
          }
        },
        {
          data: {
            source: "71",
            target: "76"
          }
        },
        {
          data: {
            source: "76",
            target: "66"
          }
        },
        {
          data: {
            source: "76",
            target: "36"
          }
        },
        {
          data: {
            source: "80",
            target: "76"
          }
        },
        {
          data: {
            source: "22",
            target: "86"
          }
        },
        {
          data: {
            source: "86",
            target: "80"
          }
        },
        {
          data: {
            source: "95",
            target: "89"
          }
        },
        {
          data: {
            source: "89",
            target: "90"
          }
        },
        {
          data: {
            source: "102",
            target: "104"
          }
        },
        {
          data: {
            source: "80",
            target: "89"
          }
        },
        {
          data: {
            source: "104",
            target: "109"
          }
        },
        {
          data: {
            source: "115",
            target: "109"
          }
        },
        {
          data: {
            source: "121",
            target: "89"
          }
        },
        {
          data: {
            source: "121",
            target: "115"
          }
        },
        {
          data: {
            source: "121",
            target: "128"
          }
        },
        {
          data: {
            source: "128",
            target: "130"
          }
        },
        {
          data: {
            source: "141",
            target: "128"
          }
        },
        {
          data: {
            source: "128",
            target: "136"
          }
        },
        {
          data: {
            source: "136",
            target: "148"
          }
        },
        {
          data: {
            source: "148",
            target: "149"
          }
        },
        {
          data: {
            source: "149",
            target: "156"
          }
        },
        {
          data: {
            source: "156",
            target: "158"
          }
        },
        {
          data: {
            source: "130",
            target: "164"
          }
        },
        {
          data: {
            source: "164",
            target: "166"
          }
        },
        {
          data: {
            source: "178",
            target: "179"
          }
        },
        {
          data: {
            source: "184",
            target: "178"
          }
        },
        {
          data: {
            source: "178",
            target: "189"
          }
        },
        {
          data: {
            source: "141",
            target: "178"
          }
        },
        {
          data: {
            source: "104",
            target: "103"
          }
        },
        {
          data: {
            source: "10",
            target: "12"
          }
        },
        {
          data: {
            source: "164",
            target: "172"
          }
        },
        {
          data: {
            source: "22",
            target: "104"
          }
        }
      ]
    }
  }));
  cy.unbind("tapend");
  cy.bind("tapend", "node", function() {
    cy.animate({
      fit: {
        eles: cy.elements(),
        padding: 20
      },
      center: {
        eles: cy.elements()
      }
    }, {
      duration: 500
    });
  });
});
```

```css
body {
  font-family: helvetica;
  font-size: 14px;
}

#cy {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  position: absolute;
  left: 0;
  top: 0;
  z-index: 999;
}

h1 {
  opacity: 0.5;
  font-size: 1em;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE>

<html>

<head>
  <title>cytoscape-cola.js demo</title>

  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, user-scalable=no, initial-scale=1, maximum-scale=1">

  <script src="https://unpkg.com/cytoscape/dist/cytoscape.min.js"></script>

  <!-- for testing with local version of cytoscape.js -->
  <!--<script src="../cytoscape.js/build/cytoscape.js"></script>-->

  <script src="https://unpkg.com/webcola/WebCola/cola.min.js"></script>
  <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/cytoscape-cola@2.3.0/cytoscape-cola.min.js"></script>

</head>

<body>
  <h1>cytoscape-cola demo</h1>

  <div id="cy"></div>

</body>

</html>
```

### **Conclusion:**

Cytoscape.js has the ability to display the force layout, but it is a little worse than the two examples you provided (they can display the graph without moving the nodes to their optimal position but the user preferred one). If you like to use cytoscape.js, you can do that just fine, but always consider which use cases you need and check, if any other application can handle the situation better (cytoscape.js has so many awesome features you can use, so if you can make it work, cytoscape would be my way to go).

Best of luck!

Answer (score 2):

You can use [force-directed layout](https://github.com/d3/d3-force) of d3.js Here is an [example graph](http://bl.ocks.org/mbostock/ad70335eeef6d167bc36fd3c04378048).

I believe Neo4j Browser also uses d3.js

From the official website:

> The default Neo4j Server has a powerful, customizable data visualization tool based on the built-in D3.js library.

Answer (score 1):

I found a video that may be similar as your question[Use of Cytoscape.js for Client project](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=IMN8j-AvZAE), also there is another extension LAYOUT with d3.js [cytoscape.js-d3-force](https://github.com/shichuanpo/cytoscape.js-d3-force)that may be a good reference.